# Unable to catch exception: another exception occurred

Tags: python, pandas, exception, index-error

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

index = 2
timestamps = pd.date_range('2019-05-01', '2019-05-01')
try:
    timestamp = timestamps[index]
except IndexError:
    raise IndexError('index is out of timestamps.')
```

that results in the following being printed to the terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py", line 1170, in __getitem__
    result = self._data.__getitem__(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py", line 426, in __getitem__
    val = getitem(key)
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: index is out of timestamps.
```

**Why is `IndexError: index is out of timestamps.` simply not raised in this instance, please?**

Comment: You catched and raised the exception

Answer (score 0):

It was raised. The traceback provides info about the former error which was handled during the latter. Since you catch the exception and raise another, the traceback info includes both.

It is written in the description:
`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

You can try and raise another type of error and see that this is the error that was raised.

Comment: Thanks. How come `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1` is also printed too? why is this not silenced and only my `IndexError: index is out of timestamps.` called?

Comment: This is the default debugging traceback that is provided by Python interpreter (when not configuring another). If an expection was raised while handling another -> provide traceback to the original exception. You can read more about tracebacks at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 0):

Because the `raise` statement in `except` block forces a new exception to handle the exception occurred in `try` block.
See [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)